Issue with chromium on AWS Lambda with 127.0.6533.99 (amd64): Chromium Stuck and Lambda Timeout
I'm using Chromedp (v0.10.0) to launch Chromium on AWS Lambda.
My setup involves deploying a Docker container based on the latest Debian image and installing the latest version of Chrome. On an arm64 architecture, everything works fine (using Chrome version 126.*). However, on an amd64 architecture, Chrome gets stuck and eventually causes the Lambda function to time out.
Interestingly, older versions of Chrome on amd64 work without issues.
Here are the flags I'm using:
chromedp.DisableGPU,
chromedp.IgnoreCertErrors,
chromedp.NoSandbox,
chromedp.Flag("use-gl", "swiftshader"),
chromedp.Flag("incognito", true),
chromedp.Flag("single-process", true),
chromedp.Flag("disable-software-rasterizer", true)

When Chrome gets stuck, I captured the Chromedp logs and noticed the following:
{\"id\":3,\"sessionId\":\"AA37AF6627E83F546FF4D68123ED353C\",\"method\":\"Runtime.enable\"}
It seems that Chrome isn't responding to this CDP command.
Additionally, here are the Chrome logs. I understand the DBus error might not be related, but I’m concerned the virtualization error could be significant:
prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS) failed prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS) failed 
[0818/153928.488373:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory 
[0818/153928.489558:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory 
[0818/153928.489640:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
[0818/153915.566510:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(953)] Failed to create GLES3 context, fallback to GLES2. 
[0818/153915.566537:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(964)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: Failed to create shared context for virtualization. 
[0818/153915.566542:ERROR:raster_command_buffer_stub.cc(88)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: Failed to create raster decoder state.

Could the virtualization error be causing the issue on amd64 with new chromium version? Are there any specific flags or configurations I should try to resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I have tried different flags for GPU but without success.
